# Unable to recover contacts from Mojave to Big Sur

Tags: backup, mojave, big-sur, contacts

I upgraded from Mojave to Big Sur and forgot to export contacts. I have a backup of the files in `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook`, which I tried to recover with the three methods mentioned in [How to restore the AddressBook database from backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29962/how-to-restore-the-addressbook-database-from-backup)

First, I quit all applications (except Terminal and Firefox), deleted the `.abcddb` file and copied it from the backup

```
$ rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook/*.abcddb 
$ cp /path/to/backup/AddressBook/AddressBook-v22.abcddb ~/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook
```

Contacts showed no cards, so the first line worked (otherwise, it would show the Apple card and my own card):

[image: no contacts screenshot]

Then, I copied the `Metadata` directory, which supposedly contains all the information in case the `.abbcddb` file goes corrupt:

```
$ rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook/*.abcddb                                                  
$ rm -r -f ~/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook/Metadata/
$ cp -r /path/to/backup/AddressBook/Metadata ~/Library/Application\ Support/AddressBook
```

Again, Contacts shows no contact information, just like above.

Third, I change the extension of the `AddressBook` directory in the backup to `.abbu` and double-click on it, which has an effect:

[image: dialog after contacts]

I click "Replace all". This does something because the `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Metadata` shows all 1,122 items and they are indexed by Spotlight. But, like before, the application itself shows no contacts.

I also have a Time Machine backup of Mojave, but because it was not set up with this computer, I cannot use it to recover contacts as in [this blog post](https://www.cisdem.com/resource/restore-contacts-from-time-machine.html).

How can I recover contacts from my backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although neither method seemed not to work, after a few days and several restarts, Contacts is now showing all the cards and the groups. Since the third method with the `.abbu` package was the only one that I didn't reset, I believe it will work.

For the future, I will avoid this issue by exporting the contacts as an archive before reinstallation.